# How to modify comments form using comment_form()?

Tags: comments, forms, comment-form

how i can modify comments form, my theme just call:

```
<?php comment_form(); ?>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding what behavior you want to change? The answer will be specific to your needed modification.

Comment: I wrote a very in depth tutorial at [Pro Blog Design.com](http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/advanced-wordpress-comment-styles-and-tricks/) that covers this topic.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean modifying its text or behavior? The function is very extensive and customizable. It both accepts extensive set of parameters and has a lot of hooks.

For starters see:

- [`comment_form()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form) in Codex;
- [WordPress 3.0 Theme Tip: The Comment Form](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-theme-tip-the-comment-form/).

Comment: This post has a lot of good info http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-theme-tip-the-comment-form/